# How to display image from server (newest-oldest) to a new php page?

Tags: php

i have a form that create images (using imagejpeg, imagettftext and imagecreatefromjpeg) and save it on a folder in the server. What i need to do is to display ALL created images to another page, the newest on the top and so that the oldest is at the bottom.  i have a form called formdisplay.php but it's just displaying a broken image and not newest to oldest. hope you can help me with this. really need to get this working. thanks in advance for your help.

i have read the posts but none of those worked for me.

[Pull dedicated images from folder - show image + filename (strip part of filename + file-extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056053/pull-dedicated-images-from-folder-show-image-filename-strip-part-of-filenam)

[How can I display latest uploaded image first? (PHP+CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557980/how-can-i-display-latest-uploaded-image-first-phpcss)

[getting images from the server and display them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359916/getting-images-from-the-server-and-display-them)

[Displaying images from folder in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795385/displaying-images-from-folder-in-php)

[display image from server embedding php in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257682/display-image-from-server-embedding-php-in-html)

formcreatesave.php

```
    imagecopymerge($im, $img2, 10, 350, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2), 100);

$date_created = date("YmdHis");//get date created
$img_name = "-img_entry.jpg"; //the file name of the generated image
$img_newname = $date_created . $img_name; //datecreated+name
$img_dir =dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ."/". $img_newname; //the location to save 
imagejpeg($im, $img_dir , 80); //function to save the image with the name and quality

imagedestroy($im);
```

formdisplay.php

```
$dir = '/home3/site/public_html/Master/uploader/uploader';
$base_url = 'http://mysite.com/Master/uploader/uploader/20131027024705-img_entry.jpg';
$newest_mtime = 0;
$show_file = 'BROKEN';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
       $mtime = filemtime("$dir/$file");
       if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
          $newest_mtime = $mtime;
          $show_file = "$base_url/$file";
       }
    }
  }
}
print '<img src="' .$show_file. '" alt="Image Title Here">';
```

please feel free to edit my code. thanks :)

Comment: place `print '<img src="' .$show_file. '" alt="Image Title Here">';` below `$show_file = "$base_url/$file";`

Comment: hi @E L i have tried your suggestion. but its still returning broken img. this time, 3 broken images. please take note that the image i was trying to display was created and saved using imagejpeg and imagecreatefromjpeg. hope you can give me further help. thanks

Comment: That's because your `$base_url` has tailing filename. Make it `$base_url = 'http://birdieonawire.com/Amadeus/uploader/uploader/';` (is it really `uploader/uploader/` dirs there?)

Comment: Yes it's there im sure. i tried using $base_url = 'http://birdieonawire.com/Amadeus/uploader/uploader/'; but its giving me 2 broken images. One linked in an errorlog the other in the font i used to write something in the created image

Comment: then it's `$dir` problem. Try to use relative path or just place `echo $show_file,'<br>';` below `$show_file = "$base_url/$file";` and see what it outputs.

Comment: i tried it but it's printing links of the formdisplay.php file, error log and font used

Comment: then its wrong `$dir` path. Use relative

Comment: its returning abroken image still. but now the link of the broken image is http://birdieonawire.com/Amadeus/uploader/uploader/BROKEN

so is it the $show_file?

Comment: and that's because it's empty dir in your `$dir` var. =) I don't know where's php file is, but I think if you set `$dir` var as `$dir='Master/uploader/uploader';` then it should dig the right dir ))

Comment: the php file is in the 'Master/uploader/uploader'. the same folder where the images i want to display is.

Comment: maybe problem is in `$newest_mtime = $mtime;`. that depends on the order of files in this dir. Just comment it `//` for testing

Comment: ok. i'll do that. i'll let you know what's the result. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Read images from folder.
2. Loop through them and insert into array with the key filetime of image.
3. Use krsort function to sort them  according  to date.
4. Loop and display them.

I think this link will help you:
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/219466-php-displaying-images-from-folder-with-most-recent-first/

Comment: Hi @Hanny Harby! I saw the code on the link you gave. it's using array. my images are not saved in an array. what can i do about this? save my image as an array? and retrieve it as an array also? thanks

Comment: Yes @Jben Kaye After you get images from server . loop through them and save them into array by filetime . then sort array by time

Comment: can you give me some sample code to do this? im not familiar with using array. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This goes after the while loop that creates the $images array (list of image filenames

```
 foreach ($images as $image)

 {

 $filetime = filemtime("images1/$image");

 $sortedimages[]$filetime => $image;

 }

 krsort($sortedimages);


 echo "<pre>";

 print_r($sortedimages);

 echo "</pre>"

 ?>
```

Comment: hi theres a sysntax error shown in the line $sortedimages[]$filetime => $image;

Comment: Thanks  @JbenKaye  Right code is  $sortedimages[$filetime] = $image;